# Replace go-swagger with another version in Windows

Tags: go, go-swagger

I am using `go1.14.1` and `go-swagger` version `dev` in my Windows 10. I installed `go-swagger` with [Installing from source](https://goswagger.io/install.html#installing-from-source).

I'd like to use `go-swagger` version [`0.25`](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/v0.25.0) instead. What is the clean way of replacing `dev` with [`0.25`](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/v0.25.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation process is same as for master (`dev`) version except you need to do one more additional step which is checking out tag `v0.25.0` after cloning the repo to temporary directory:

```sh
dir=$(mktemp -d) 
git clone https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger "$dir" 
cd "$dir"

# Checkout version v0.25.0
git checkout v0.25.0

# Continue with installation, instead of
# go install ./cmd/swagger

# use this which just adds version information (current tag) and commit id to binary
go install -ldflags "-X github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger/commands.Version=$(git describe --tags) -X github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger/commands.Commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)" ./cmd/swagger
```

NOTE: If you do just `go install ./cmd/swagger` it will technically still install v0.25.0 but `swagger version` subcommand will report it as `dev`. The version information is just a cosmetic thing passed from git repository down as content of variables in `commands` package and you can see how authors do it in their CircleCI config file [here](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L50). Eventually you can add also other flags to get static build (but they don't do that in official *Installing from source* instructions).

Once done you should have go-swagger v0.25.0 installed in your `$GOPATH/bin`, verify with:

```sh
$ swagger version
version: v0.25.0
commit: f032690aab0634d97e2861a708d8fd9365ba77d2
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to get the version information correct for source installs. Had troubles with that before, would be nice if this was part of the doc somewhere.